# jQuery add event

Tags: jquery, css

The following jQuery code adds an event by calling a function `scroll_position`

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "scroll", scroll_position);

function scroll_position() {
        var p = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        jQuery(scrollbox).css('position',((p+10)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'absolute');
        jQuery(scrollbox).css('top',((p+10)>start) ? '10px' : '');
    }
```

Is it possible to add this event without using the function scroll_position? I mean, I just want to do same thing without using a function. (I dont have any reason for not using the function, just learning the jQuery).

Comment: What do you mean by not using a function? What event do you want to trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need a event for when you do not want to do anything with it?

You can do inline functions, e.g.

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
    alert("magic happens here");
});
```

thus ridding yourself of the need of a function of your own...

Comment: oh thats what i meant, the inline function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind the event hung .bind or .live and then trigger it whenever you wany using .trigger

No need for jQuery.event.add